# SQL Presto - Week function to star on a Sunday

Tags: sql, presto, week-number

I'm trying to extract the week number from a date, and I want the week to be counted from Sunday to Saturday. This is what I currently have, but I can't seem to find any solution for this is SQL Presto.

```
SELECT WEEK(date) AS weeknum
```

Can this be solved?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/2379

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select week(date + interval '1 day') - interval '1 day'
```

Note:  This may not work on the last day of the year.

Alternatively you can use the MySQL-like functions:

```
select date_format(date, '%V')
```

This has the week starting on Sunday.